# Symbol for a potentiometer on a guitar amp layout diagram

Tags: amplifier, potentiometer, layout, guitar-amplifier

[image]

Was working to convert a guitar amp layout diagram to schematic and stumbled upon this component. Looks like a potentiometer but has some additional tabs on the front. The label reads "master". Anyone knows what I am dealing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a potentiometer with an integrated switch. Turning it all the way counterclockwise opens the switch, otherwise it is closed.

Comment: Push-pull variations are available too.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a schematic symbol, technically speaking. It's a crude *drawing* of the potentiometer! Here's a slightly different perspective on the same type of part:

[image: a potentiometer with switch]

The three terminals on top of your diagram are the ends and wiper for the potentiometer (with the wiper in the middle), and the two terminals on the back are the switch, which probably switches off when the potentiometer is at one end.